# Как соеденить список с каждым [i][j] элементом второго списка

Tags: python, list

нужно соединить список с другим в формате как показано на скриншоте и записать в файл , списки могут быть разной длины .Пробовал соединить через цикл соединить, но получалось белиберда   P.s извиняюсь за описание больше надеюсь на скриншоты из за не грамотности сложно описать что я хочу

на входе

['2', '4', '3']

[[46], [46, 66, 36], [46, 36]]

на выходе

2 [46]

4 [46,66,36]

3[46,36]

[image: пример так так должно записываться в файл]

Comment: вы хотите вывести на экран элементы двух списков с одинаковыми индексами? добавьте в вопрос вашу реалицачию (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1258280/edit)) и уточните, что не работает и как как долно быть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1258280/edit))

Comment: я хочу записать в файл 2 разных списка например [2,3,4,5] [[30],[30,40][50,60,70][80,90,100,110]] и записать их в файл в таком формате 2[30] \n 3 [30,40] \n 4[50,60,70] \n5[80,90,100,110]

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно что-то такое:

```py
a = ['2', '4', '3']
b = [[46], [46, 66, 36], [46, 36]]
with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in zip(a,b):
        print(*i, file=f)
```

Comment: можно узнать поподробнее про zip()

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip